# Targeting <a> with specific attribute using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape a page that has a section like this:

```
<a name="id_631"></a>

<hr>

<div class="store-class">
    <div>
        <span><strong>Store City</strong</span>
    </div>

    <div class="store-class-content">
        <p>Event listing</p>
        <p>Event listing2</p>
        <p>Event listing3</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        Stuff about contact info
    </div>
</div>
```

The page is a list of sections like that and the only way to differentiate them is by the name attribute in the `<a>` tag.

So I'm thinking I want to target that then go to the next_sibling to get the `<hr>` then again to the next sibling to get the `<div class="store-class">` section. All I want is the info in that div tag.

I'm not sure how to target that `<a>` tag to move down two siblings though. When I try `print(soup.find_all('a', {"name":"id_631"}))` that just gives me what's in the tag, which is nothing.

Here's my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.tandyleather.com/en/leathercraft-classes")

soup = soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("a", id="id_631").find_next_sibling("div", class_="store-class"))
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tandy.py", line 8, in <module>
print(soup.find("a", id="id_631").find_next_sibling("div", class_="store-class"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to the rescue:

```
soup.find("a", attrs={"name": "id_631"}).find_next_sibling("div", class_="store-class")
```

Also, `html.parser` has to replaced with either `lxml` or `html5lib`.

See also:

- [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: I tried that and updated my original post with the error.

Comment: @JamesWhite okay, the actual page HTML is a bit different from provided in the question. What is your desired output? Thanks.

Comment: I want the info inside div.store-class. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesWhite okay, but you can locate the "store-class" elements directly via, for instance `soup.find_all("div", class_="store-class")` - is there a problem with this approach?..

Comment: There's a lot of div.store-class on the page. The only way to identify the store you want is with the name="id_631".

Comment: @JamesWhite I got it, updated - should work for you.

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'` But searching the page source I only find one name="id_631".

Comment: @JamesWhite my bad, fixed.

Comment: Now I get an empty array. I'm going to keep playing with it also. At least I'm not getting an error anymore!

Comment: @JamesWhite okay, got it. You have to use `lxml` or `html5lib` instead of `html.parser` in this case.

Comment: That was it with one small change. It should be find_next_sibling. Not plural. THANK YOU!